# FileStream does not save array files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient, filestream

I have array links. Each of link presents one XML file. How can I iterate each XML and save to folder with one call.

*`GetMesssageAttachments(userId)`* return array 6 links, but current code save only first file. What's wrong here? Thanks

```
 public async void SaveXMLMessages(string userId)
    {
                try
                {
                    if (_responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string messagesFolder = @"C:\XMLMessages";
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(messagesFolder);

                        string messageFileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
                        string messagesPath = Path.Combine(messagesFolder, messageFileName);

                        foreach (string xmlMessage in await GetMesssageAttachments(userId))
                        {
                            var xmlMessageResponse = await _client.GetAsync(xmlMessage);
                            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(messagesPath, FileMode.Create))
                            {
                                await xmlMessageResponse.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e.InnerException;
                }
            }
```

> UPDATED

This is work..

```
    public async void SaveXMLMessages(string userId)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string messagesFolder = @"C:\XMLMessages";
                Directory.CreateDirectory(messagesFolder);

                foreach (string xmlMessage in await GetMesssageAttachments(userId))
                {
                    string messageFileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
                    string messagesPath = Path.Combine(messagesFolder, messageFileName);

                    var xmlMessageResponse = await _client.GetAsync(xmlMessage);
                    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(messagesPath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await xmlMessageResponse.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e.InnerException;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you aren't generating a new file name each time.

Answer (score 3):

Same `messagesPath` used in `foreach`. That means there is only one file created in loop

You must reinitialize it in the loop like this:

```
foreach (string xmlMessage in await GetMesssageAttachments(userId))
{
    string messageFileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
    string messagesPath = Path.Combine(messagesFolder, messageFileName);
    var xmlMessageResponse = await _client.GetAsync(xmlMessage);
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(messagesPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await xmlMessageResponse.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are overwriting files in each iteration, try moving this block to inside your foreach:

```
string messageFileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
string messagesPath = Path.Combine(messagesFolder, messageFileName);
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works. I was trying before but just it was missing something and code didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Only small change in 'thierry v' code and what rsb55 is saying is right. Your code should look like as below

```
foreach (string xmlMessage in await GetMesssageAttachments(userId))
{
string messageFileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
string messagesPath = Path.Combine(messagesFolder, messageFileName);

    var xmlMessageResponse = await _client.GetAsync(xmlMessage);
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(messagesPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await xmlMessageResponse.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
}
```